# Are there any java collection wrappers/collections that fail upon multithreaded access?

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

I'm trying to track some concurrency problems related to collections in a large code-base.

I would like to replace all the collections/maps with an alternate implementation that throws an exception when the 3rd thread accesses it (or similar; I can see several possible strategis that might work). Anyone know of any libraries/tools/strategies to do this ?

I was thinking about doing a search-replace in the entire code-base and just temporarily replace any reference to stuff like "new HashMap" with a different version. But maybe there's a better way ?

Comment: Dr Cliff Click at Azul Systems did a piece on exactly this where they have a drop-in replacement for the collections that error on concurrent access, but I can't find the article (can't remember if it was a blog piece or a different presentation): http://blogs.azulsystems.com/cliff/

Answer (score 2):

You could try to wrap the HashMap get() and put() methods (or whatelse you use) with ReentrantLock:

```
java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock



class X {
 private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

     public void m() { 
         if ( ! lock.tryLock() ) {
            // already locked, hint: lock.isHeldByCurrentThread() ?
         }
         lock.lock();
         try {
           // delegate to wrapped hashMap
         } 
         finally {
           lock.unlock()
         }
     }
```

Comment: +1 for a nice solution, but that'd actually require concurrent access to happen. I think my solution would allow me to explore the general concurrent usage a bit better in a large an largely unknown code base

Answer (score 2):

Since there were no obvious takers, [I made my own](http://github.com/krosenvold/failfast-collections):

Found 29 potential concurrency issues in three hours on a large code-base.